# How to put linebreak after text with docxtemplater

Tags: javascript, docxtemplater

I'm using the docxtemplater module to fill template on a MS Word document. I've used this, but it just add space to the template:

```
var EOL = "\n";
var willBeTemplated = "Something" + EOL;
```

How can I put a line break after this text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of docxtemplater.

You can use the following code :

```js
const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {linebreaks: true});
```

By default, docxtemplater does'nt take into account linebreaks, but with this option it will add them.

https://docxtemplater.com/docs/faq/#inserting-new-lines

Comment: I can ask you for advice regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68002166/react-js-read-the-text-of-a-doc-docx-file